# Additional Criteria for function to have one minima

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization

I have a function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ that I want to find the region of the local minima for through some algorithm (ie coordinate descent). However I want to make sure it is the only minima when $x_j>0$ by proving this function only has one minima.

However, this function is really complex (and I want to be able to generalize it to higher dimensions) so I was hoping to learn about some additional tests to see if I could apply them. Here is some additional information I know:

1. $f$ is $C^\infty$ on the domain in question
2. Define $g(x) = f(k_1, k_2, \ldots, x, \ldots, k_n)$ in which all variables except one are fixed. **It is known that $g$ has only one minima**
3. As any variable grows arbitrarily large, $f$ grows arbitrarily large
4. The epigraph of $f$ is likely not convex.

To provide some details (without making it too much), but for any fixed values of $k_j$, we can say that $g(x)$ is always of the form
$$
g(x) = \log(xp_1+p_2) - \frac{p_3}{p_4^x} + p_5
$$
where the values $p$ are parameters based on which values you fix.

Comment: Can you  please define what you mean by item (3)? In particular, do you mean one of the following notions?

*A*: $\lim_{\|\overline{x}\|\to +\infty} f(\overline{x}) = +\infty$, or are you saying *B*: For every $m\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $\lim_{x_m\to+\infty} f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,x_m,\ldots,k_n)=+\infty$ (where the $k_i$, terms are constants)?

Comment: Based on what is written, it might not be true that your function always has a unique minimizer. Some keywords to look up are "coercivity" (which guarantees a minimizer) and "supercoercivity" (which guarantees a *unique* minimizer).  You could also use recession theory if you wanna get fancy. A good reference (for grad-level stuff on this) is "Asymptotic cones and functions in optimization and variational inequalities" by alfred auslender and marc teboulle

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you right: you are looking for sufficient conditions such that $f$ has a unique global minimum for positive arguments? And item (4) is meant to say the more obvious (strict) convexity conditions are off the table?

Comment: @Zim item (3) is the second thing you defined, in which as any individual value grows arbitrarily large the function will too. Also thank you for the reference I will check that out. Also bodhi yes that's what I am asking, and yeah (4) is to say that the function is not convex which would have made my life so much easier haha